# Getting an unexpected "?" at the end of a Registry GetValue

Tags: c#, registry

I use the Registry class to manage values in the Registry on Windows Seven in C#.

```
Registry.GetValue(...);
```

But, I'm facing a curious behavior :
Every time, the returned value is the correct one, but sometimes, it is followed by an unexpected "?"

When I check the Registry, (regedit), the "?" doesn't exist.
I really don't understand from where this question mark come from.

Info :

- C#
- 3.5 framework
- windows 7 64 bits (and i want my application to work on both 32 and 64 bits systems)

Comment: A couple of questions for you,.. (1) Is it differing registry keys that are returning values suffixed with "?", or is it only a subset? (2) Have you tried compiling targeting 64bit and 32bit and confirming that it occurs when targeting both specifically?

Comment: Also, is that an actual question mark character, or is it some other unprintable character?

Comment: @Rob : (1) I made my tests on only one key
(2) I didn't try. I compil a ddl that is loaded by another soft (AutoCAD), that can be 32 bits or 64 bis.

@ John Saunders : I have to check. I get a "?" when I log the value.

Comment: It seems that it is not a "?".

The test EndsWith("?") fails even when my logs show me a "?".

Is there any method that could check for an unpritable character ?

Comment: Why do you think the last character is ?.  It's far more likely that it's a unicode character which can't be converted to ANSI...

I'd access the last character and dump it as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

That didn't quite work for me, I was also getting a random ? at the end of a value from the registry that was a file path. It only appeared every now and again. It seems like a bug.

I use 2 pass method to see if directory exists and then strip out characters, I was getting unicode character 1792 at the end. < 128 probably won't work for some languages.

```
string configPath = val.ToString();
bool dirExists = false;
if (Directory.Exists(configPath))
{
    dirExists = true;
}
else
{

    _logger.Warn("The path for service {0} doesn't exist: {1}", serviceName, configPath);

    StringBuilder configPathBuilder = new StringBuilder(configPath.Length);

    // Do this to remove any dodgy characters in the path like a ? at end
    char[] inValidChars = Path.GetInvalidPathChars();
    foreach (Char c in configPath.ToCharArray())
    {
        if (inValidChars.Contains(c) == false && c < 128)
        {
            configPathBuilder.Append(c);
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.Warn("An invalid path was character was found in the path: {0} {1}", c, (int)c);
        }
    }

    configPath = configPathBuilder.ToString();

    if (Directory.Exists(configPath))
    {
        dirExists = true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So my question is, "who set the value"?

Perhaps whoever did the setting put in an unprintable character at the end of the string.  It is probably not actually a question mark.  This may be a result of a bug in the program which did the setting, not anything to do with your code, per se.

Comment: Here are some answers :
The key has been set by me on "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MySoft\"
I set a value that corresponds to a file path (keyname : "path", value "C:\....\MyFile.txt"

When I get the value, I just want to get this filePath.

I made a test, that only get this value and LOG this value.
I ran this test a few times (everytime on the same key).
Most of time I got the correct filePath ("C:\....\MyFile.txt"), and a few times, "C:\....\MyFile.txt?"

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to remove the unexpected char, thanks to all your comments ;)

```
 String value = null;
        try
        {
            foreach (Char item in Registry.GetValue(registryKey, key, "").ToString().ToCharArray())
            {
                if (Char.GetUnicodeCategory(item) != System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory.OtherLetter && Char.GetUnicodeCategory(item) != System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory.OtherNotAssigned)
                {
                    value += item;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LOG.Error("Unable to get value of " + key + ex, ex);
        }
        return value;
```

I made some tests to know what kind of char appears from time to time. It was, just like you said Larry, an unicode problem.
I still don't understand why this char appears sometimes.